# Python 3.11 img2pdf module does not accept a list of images

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, customtkinter, img2pdf

Basically, i want to build an GUI, that will take a files, directories where to save and name of pdf-file, and then convers images to pdf and save. Here is my code:

```
from img2pdf import convert
import customtkinter as ctk
import tkinter as tk
import os

ctk.set_appearance_mode('dark')
ctk.set_default_color_theme('blue')

app = ctk.CTk()
app.geometry('400x500')
app.title('Image to PDF comverter')

image_paths = []
path = ''

def ask_download_directory():
    global path
    selected_path = ctk.filedialog.askdirectory()
    path = selected_path
    download_path_label.configure(text=path)

def ask_file_directory():
    file_types = (
    ("JPEG files", "*.jpg"),
    ("PNG files", "*.png"),
    ("GIF files", "*.gif"),
    ("Bitmap files", "*.bmp"),
    ("TIFF files", "*.tiff"),
    ("All image files", "*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.png;*.gif;*.bmp;*.tiff;*.tif")
)
    selected_files = ctk.filedialog.askopenfilenames(filetypes=file_types)
    image_paths.extend(selected_files)
    file_chose_label.configure(text='\n'.join([item.split('/')[-1] for item in image_paths]))

def ask_name():
    dialog = ctk.CTkInputDialog(text="Введите имя будщего файла:", title="Ввод имени файла")
    return dialog.get_input()

def download():
    name = ask_name()
    output_pdf = f'{path}/{name}.pdf'
    with open(output_pdf, 'wb') as pdf_file:
        pdf_file.write(convert(images=image_paths))

file_chose_button = ctk.CTkButton(master=app, width=30, height=30,
                                  text='Выберите файлы', command=ask_file_directory)
file_chose_button.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.1, anchor=tk.CENTER)

file_chose_label = ctk.CTkLabel(master=app, text='')
file_chose_label.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.3, anchor=tk.CENTER)

download_path_label = ctk.CTkLabel(master=app)
download_path_label.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.6375, anchor=tk.CENTER)
image_paths = [path for path in image_paths if os.path.isfile(path)]
download_path_button = ctk.CTkButton(master=app, width=30, height=30,
                            text='Выберите путь для загрузки', command=ask_download_directory)
download_path_button.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.55, anchor=tk.CENTER)

path = download_path_label.cget('text')

download_button = ctk.CTkButton(master=app, width=30, height=30,
                                  text='Загрузить в выбранную папку', command=download)
download_button.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.725, anchor=tk.CENTER)

app.mainloop()

print(image_paths)
```

When i chose two .jpg images, it creates an PDF-file, but it doesn't open and in terminal error is raised:
`ValueError: Unable to process empty list`

Full error message:

````
    Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1948, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\makha\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\customtkinter\windows\widgets\ctk_button.py", line 554, in _clicked
    self._command()
  File "c:\Users\makha\Рабочий стол\Учёба\Программирование\Python\Мини-проекты\Image to PDF converter\main.py", line 43, in download
    pdf_file.write(convert(images=image_paths))
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\makha\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\img2pdf.py", line 2320, in convert
    raise ValueError("Unable to process empty list")
ValueError: Unable to process empty list
['C:/Users/makha/Рабочий стол/capacitors.jpg', 'C:/Users/makha/Рабочий стол/logo_KBTU.jpg']```
````

Here is what image_paths outputs in terminal:
`['C:/Users/makha/Рабочий стол/capacitors.jpg', 'C:/Users/makha/Рабочий стол/logo_KBTU.jpg']`

Also, to solve this problem i tries to pass to convert() function an list

```
from PIL import Image
[Image.open(img) for img in image_paths]
```

Didn't work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include the full traceback error.